# Cannot find apply_gradients in adamOptimizer in keras or tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras, gradient-descent

apply_gradients might have been removed in future versions of optimizer in tensorflow or keras. DO not know why but I am getting this:

> AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'apply_gradients'

Any other way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Are you using the correct keras version? This is only for `tensorflow.keras`.

Comment: ok, let me cheak

Comment: Alright I was using the keras one instead of tensorflow.keras, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply_gradients` is something that is only possible in `tensorflow.keras`, because you can make manual training loops with eager execution on.

Pure `keras` must use symbolic graph and can only apply gradients with `fit` or `train_on_batch`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In the end, this initializer worked:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
```

But these lead to the error:

```
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
optimizer = tf.python.keras.optimizers.Adam()
```